# Why angular translate doesn't work if no html tag before?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-translate

I'm using Angular translate with ionic. I want to use a syntax like:

```
{{ 'SOME_TEXT' | translate }}
```

But that doesn't work.

If I use:

```
<small translate='SOME_TEXT'></small>
```

That works, and if I use then in the html:

```
{{ 'SOME_TEXT' | translate }}
```

This time works. But why it doesn't work if I use them no using the small tag?

In my app file, I have this config:

```
$translateProvider
    .useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'locales/',
        suffix: '.json'
    })
    .registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'de'], {
        'en': 'en', 'en_GB': 'en', 'en_US': 'en',
        'de': 'de', 'de_DE': 'de', 'de_CH': 'de'
    })
    .preferredLanguage('de')
    .fallbackLanguage('de')
    .determinePreferredLanguage()
    .useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters');
```

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: How have you configured your TranslateService?

Comment: What are you using? AngularJS or Angular 2 / Ionic or Ionic 2?

Comment: I added the configuration. If I don't write the small tag with the translate attribute, I simply become SOME_TEXT and not the translation. I can write this at the begin the page and the write multiples other translation and work fine, but it must to be a time the translate attribute something... I use angular 1 and ionic 1

Comment: Please remove angular2 tag from the post .

Comment: Can you replicate in Plunker?